# How to stop read receipt request?

Tags: c#

i am sending bulk email using

```
System.Net.Mail

SmtpClient objSmtpClient = null; objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(GlobalInfo.strFirstSmtpServer, GlobalInfo.intFirstSmtpPort);

if (GlobalInfo.bolFirstIsUseDefaultCredentials != null)
    objSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = GlobalInfo.bolFirstIsUseDefaultCredentials.Value;
objSmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(GlobalInfo.strFirstSmtpUser, GlobalInfo.strFirstSmtpPassword);
if (GlobalInfo.bolFirstIsEnableSSL != null)
    objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = GlobalInfo.bolFirstIsEnableSSL.Value;
    objSmtpClient.Send(mail);
```

in c# and i am receiving auto email alert of email read. How can i stop auto email read alert. I google but i cannot find any appropriate answer. Thanks

Comment: how u setup the auto email alert by service or configured somewhere

Comment: i configured it

Comment: change there in configuration =D